# Swift init via KeyPath / WritableKeyPath

Tags: swift, initialization, kvc, keypaths, swift-keypath

Is there any way to initialize a Swift type by setting its properties via Key Path?

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var number: Int
    
    init(to number: Int) {
        self.number = number // ok
    }
    
    init(viaKeyPathTo number: Int) {
        self[keyPath: \.number] = number // error
    }
}
```

Attempting to initialize via key path fails with the errors:

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

If the property uses `let` rather than `var`, it gives the error:

> Cannot assign through subscript: key path is read-only

Setting properties via key path in `init` appears to not function. Why not? Are there any workarounds?

Has this issue been discussed or proposed in the open source Swift Evolution process?

Comment: I’m curious, what would you use this for? Swift enforces definite initialization, and that would only really make sense to allow for hard-coded literal key paths. If dynamic values were allowed, then knowing which properties were set require data flow analysis to determine the possible key path values that would make it to the call site. That’s an undecidable problem (it’s isomorphic to the halting problem). If the key path is forced to be a literal value, then that begs the question: why not just use dot notation as normal?

Comment: @Alexander I have a core data model with 30+ attributes. In code, I generally collect them in a dictionary. Then I have a String > KeyPath mapping that can set properties on the managed object via the Strings/Dictionary. But I guess that can't be used to initialize the object...

Comment: Ahh, so this is an XY problem. You can do what you're trying to achieve using Codable. And actually, doesn't Core Data integrate heavily with NSCoding? No keypaths or manual mappings from strings to keypaths would be necessary.

Comment: What you're trying to do is actually possible using keypaths, but as I alluded to earlier, you can't satisfy Swift's definition initialization requirement with dynamic keypaths. However, an escape-hatch for this exist, in the form of implicitly unwrapped optionals. All your properties would need to be IUOs. Now, that might sound bad, but it's not so bad in context, when you consider that most object references in  most languages are implicitly nullable, and dangerous to deference, just like IUOs. However, Codable exists now, and would fit this well.

Comment: Yeah, I have a workaround for my object. Here is a similar question on Swift Evolution: https://forums.swift.org/t/property-initialization-using-a-keypath-within-an-init-method/35034